# Eclipse Command Line Plugin

Tags: eclipse, shell, command-line, build, scripting

I need an Eclipse Plugin run shell scripts under Linux. I have a beautiful Rsync script and I want a button in Eclipse to activate it.

The best Solution would be if the Rsync shell script was also activated when I was saving Stuff, so maybe I can add a script builder or something like that.

Anyone has a clue for both of the solutions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the eclipse [external tools feature](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fconcepts-exttools.htm). For running shell scripts put in the location field `/bin/sh` and the argument should be the shell script itself.

If you want to run a script when saving you can use the internal builders of Eclipse.

Project -> Properties -> Builders -> New... -> Program

Be sure you check the "After a Clean", "During auto build" options on the "Build Options" tab.

Comment: Thank you very much, the Builders Feature is exactly what i wanted. I can even show the Output of the Rsync Script on the Console. Now my Server is always in sync with my Dev Machine, bye bye FTP

Comment: Found a new Answer ... Netbeans ;D

Answer (score 0):

I am now using Netbeans!

The 7.0 Beta has a great **included Command Line**, **FTP / SFTP Support with Public Keys** and **works great for Linux and PHP**.

I was hesistant to change but now I like it even more than Eclipse. Only thing that I miss is my really fast Rsync Script, but one les thing to care about!

```
# !/bin/sh

#Important Notes:
# 0) Requrirements: RSYNC and SSH support on your Machine (install cygwin under windows, all good OS should already have it)
# 1) You have to configure your ssh so yout do not have to enter the Password and the Port for your Server
# 2) You have to edit the Paths and directorys to fit your Environment
# 3) You may be interested in changing some RSYNC Options
# 4) You may want to add this Script as Eclipse Builder to be run on autosave, to always keep your Server in sync.
```

Here is the Script if somebody wants to use it with Eclipse.

You just have to set up some environment Variables in Eclipse ($USER etc.). Worked great for me until i found Netbeans.

```
# Push: rsync [OPTION...] SRC... [USER@]HOST:DEST

# Useful rsync Options
# -v verbose
# -q quiet, supress non-error Messages
# -r recursive, recurse sub-directorys
# -u update, skip files that are newer on the server
# -E preserve Executability
# --chmod=CHMOD directory permissions to be set
# -z compress file data during transfer
# --compress-level NUM explicitly set compression level
# --skip-compress=LIST skip compressing files with suffix in list (for jpg, png)
# --exclude=PATTERN (for svn and eclipse config files)
# --port (maybe we want a weird port)
# -h output numbers in a human readable format (that is always good)
# --progress (may be interesting)
# --password-file read daemon-access password from file
# --bwlimit=KBPS bandwith limit
# -t transfer the modification times with the files ... makes next transfer more effective
# --delete delete files that do not exist on other side
# -C cvs-exclude - exclude RCS   SCCS   CVS   CVS.adm   RCSLOG  cvslog.*  tags  TAGS .make.state .nse_depinfo *~ #* .#* ,* _$* *$ *.old  *.bak *.BAK  *.orig *.rej .del-* *.a *.olb *.o *.obj *.so *.exe *.Z *.elc *.ln core .svn/ .git/ .bzr/
# --stats ... could be interesting

TARGET_HOST="www.example.com"
TARGET_DIR="/var/www/"
TARGET_USER="root"

SOURCE_DIR="/home/user/workspace/myeclipseproject/"

#Make this Variable empty if you do not want nonexisting Files on the Server to be deleted
#DELETE=" --delete"
DELETE=""

OPTIONS=" -r -u -E -z -h --progress -t --stats --chmod=a+rwx --exclude-from=exclude.txt --chmod=a+rwx "$DELETE

COMMAND="$OPTIONS  $SOURCE_DIR $TARGET_USER@$TARGET_HOST:$TARGET_DIR"
echo 'rsync '$COMMAND
rsync  $COMMAND
```